# iOS scroll to a section in a UITable View

Tags: ios, uitableview

does anyone know how to programatically scroll a table view to a section at index path. what i'm trying to do is have tableview with 2 sections and an if statement for example

```
if loading = true scroll the table view up to hide the first section
when finished loading scroll table view back down to show first section
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand your requirements. How do you want to scroll *up* to hide the first section? Are you trying to implement some kind of pull to refresh?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the snippet:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```