# iOS - Scrolling to the top of a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app there is a UITableView with six sections. While the number of rows is increasing, I think that the user should have the option to scroll quickly to the top of the tableView.
I am thinking about including a button on the title header to perform the scrolling action.
I have seen in SO a similar question to my problem here:

[iOS scroll to a section in a UITable View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069080/ios-scroll-to-a-section-in-a-uitable-view)

But I don't know where to include the code given in the answer to the question and also I don't know what to put for the param `inSection`:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Assuming you want to scroll to the top of the current section:
```

I advise a private variable to save the indexPath of a current cell. Then in your button in the top, when a user wants to go to the top of the section, you can access the section from that indexPath.

```
//in the .m file at the top
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSIndexPath *pathSoFar;
```

Remember to instantiate it. You can probably set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and let the UIButton in the navigation quickly access `self.pathSoFar.section` for that piece of code you already have.

Btw, this assumes you want to scroll to the top of a particular section and not the very top. If (scroll to very top) use 0 for section and row.

Comment: I will try both options, to scroll to the top a particular section, and to scroll to the very top. At the second option I will include an action to collapse all rows from the tableview. Thank you

Comment: If I use 0 for section and 0 for row, the tableView scrolls to the top of the section indexed as 1. But I get a compiler exception when using  pathSoFar, what should I exactly put on my cellForRowAtIndexPath to get pathSofar, and how to substitute row and section when using pathSoFar?..Thank you

Comment: I will use following to scroll to the top of the tableView: [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can jump to the top of a UITableview by simply tapping the status bar (where the clock is?). Give it a go - no button required!

I believe this works for the first UIScrollView in a UIViewController.

Comment: Your advice is working, but I guess it should be better to add a button to perform this scrolling, then I want to add also an action to collapse the rows from all sections.

Comment: this is a nifty gesture by Apple, but some users just don't know about it

Comment: @mattkc7 Yes, true. I only learned of it recently by accident

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```